# jQuery Mobile how to check if button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I disable the button like this on my jQuery Mobile webpage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deliveryNext").button();
    $("#deliveryNext").button('disable');
});
```

and i can enable it with

```
$("#deliveryNext").button('enable');
```

But how do i check if the button is disabled or enabled?

This command gives "undefined":

```
$("#deliveryNext").attr('disabled')
```

Some ideas?

Edit: i find out that $("#deliveryNext").button('disable') only seams to change the style on the button, the clicking works fine after so i need to disable the button some how also.. i tried .attr('disabled', 'disabled') but when i then test .attr('disabled') i get undefined...

Edit2: more about my "real" problem at [How to disable a link button in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438659/how-to-disable-a-link-button-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 135):

try `:is` selector

```
$("#deliveryNext").is(":disabled")
```

Comment: Use ".prop('disabled')" instead.

Comment: @tponthieux Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 29):

Use .prop instead:

```
$('#deliveryNext').prop('disabled')
```

Comment: thats gives me the same result, if i writing this in firebug:
console.log($('#deliveryNext').prop('disabled'))
i getting "undefined"

Comment: Works for me in FireFox.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you may need hasClass("disabled") for tag A as well.

Answer (score 16):

Faced with the same issue when trying to check if a button is disabled. I've tried a variety of approaches, such as `btn.disabled`, `.is(':disabled')`, `.attr('disabled')`, `.prop('disabled')`. But no one works for me.

Some, for example `.disabled` or `.is(':disabled')` returned `undefined` and other like `.attr('disabled')` returned the wrong result - `false` when the button was actually disabled.

But only one technique **works for me**: **`.is('[disabled]')`** (*with square brackets*).

So to determine if a button is disabled try this:

```
$("#myButton").is('[disabled]');
```

Comment: take my money. This worked. i'm using an anchor tag with just `<a href="..." disabled>Test</a>` Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$("#deliveryNext").is(":disabled")
```

The following code works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testButton").button();
        $("#testButton").button('disable');
        alert($('#testButton').is(':disabled'));
    });
</script>
<p>
    <button id="testButton">Testing</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Gives me false but the button is disabled with $('#deliveryNext').button('disable')

Comment: Does the element have the disabled tag when your disable it? (You can check through firebug)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I found this is working:

```
if ($("#deliveryNext").attr('disabled')) {
  // do sth if disabled
} else {
  // do sth if enabled 
}
```

If this gives you undefined then you can use `if` condition also.

When you evaluate `undefined` it will return `false`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$("#deliveryNext").is('[disabled]');
```

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/8gfYZ/11/
Check here..

```
$(function(){

    $('#check').click(function(){
        if( $('#myButton').prop('disabled') ) { 
            alert('disabled'); 
            $('#myButton').prop('disabled',false);
        } 
        else {
            alert('enabled');
            $('#myButton').prop('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To see which options have been set on a **jQuery UI** button use:

```
$("#deliveryNext").button('option')
```

To check if it's disabled you can use:

```
$("#deliveryNext").button('option', 'disabled')
```

Unfortunately, if the button hasn't been explicitly enabled or disabled before, the above call will just return the button object itself so you'll need to first check to see if the options object contains the 'disabled' property.

So to determine if a button is disabled you can do it like this:

```
$("#deliveryNext").button('option').disabled != undefined && $("#deliveryNext").button('option', 'disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#StartButton:disabled') ..

Then check if it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function along with [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector:

```js
$("#savematerial").is(":disabled")
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was this:

```
$("#testButton").hasClass('ui-state-disabled')
```

But I like tomwadley's answer a lot more.

Nevertheless, the is(':disabled') code does also not work for me which should be the best version. Don't know, why it does not work. :-(